# Click outside div and close div, even if div is not a child of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two div's that I open that kinda belong together, but for programming reasons can't be connected. I simplified the code here because it's a lot of code. This is the basic.

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="div1">
     <div> when I am clicked I will open div2 </div>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
     <div> I can be clicked and all the div's stay open </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And this is the connected JavaScript

```
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#div1");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      container.hide();
    }
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#div2");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      container.hide();
    }
  });
```

Now what I would like to do is when I click outside `div1` it should close `div1`.

When I click on `div1` it opens `div2`.

Currently with the above when I click in `div2` it closes `div1`, because it is not a child of `div1`. So it should keep `div2` opened.

And when I click outside `div1` or `div2` it should close the two div's.

How can I combine the two JavaScript codes to get the explained behaviour?

**Summary of what I try to accomplish:**

1. Click on the div inside `div1` will open `div2`
2. Click outside `div1` or `div2` will close both `div1` and `div2`.
3. In case the div inside `div1` is not clicked and one clicks outside
   `div1`, it should close `div1`.

Comment: You definitely should not use the exact event twice. Everything you need to do should be done within the first `$(document).mouseup(function (e)..`

Comment: agree with that

Comment: That's where `stopPropagation()` becomes handy... When you have no choice due to a bad (or real complex) desing.

Comment: I saw your edit... Have a look (again?) at my answer (I also edited a couple times) and tell me what doesn't fix what you wish.

Comment: something went wrong with the edit, but i guess it worked now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Comment: @Maxim: I agree... The dup you suggest is real close to charlietfl's answer. My answer is another approach to solve the same problem. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `closest()`  and a common class makes this simpler

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  !$(e.target).closest('.content').length &&  $('.content').hide(); 
});

$('#div1').click(function() {
  $('#div2').show();
})
```

```css
#div2{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1" class="content">
    <div> when i am clicked i will open div2 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="content">
    <div> i can be clicked and all the div's stay open </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very nice, just add two 'dummy' classes and just a simple line of code

Comment: Good thing about closest() is it also includes the selector element itself, not just it's descendants

Answer (score 1):

Pretty theorical....

But requirements are quite clear. I would do it using `.stopPropagation()`.

`e.target` is the element clicked. If it is a child of an element having a "concurring handler" on the same event, the handler **from the parent** will execute. Except if you **stop the propagation**, which you should look at [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

Having a handler on a top-most parent that say "hide all", will will overcome the handler of the child saying somthing else. So in this case... From the child, you do not want the click (or mouseup... or whatever the event) to propagate to the top parent.

**In short**: `.stopPropagation()` will keep the event on the releveant element and you can "not care about" any concurring handler from the parents.

```js
$("#div1").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  whoAmI(e);
  $("#div2").show();
});

$("#div2").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  whoAmI(e);
  console.log("I was clicked and #div1 stayed opened.");
});

$("#container").on("click",function(e){
  $("#div1,#div2").hide();
  whoAmI(e);
});

function whoAmI(e){
console.clear();
  console.log( "I'm "+e.target.tagName+" "+((e.target.id=='')? "child" : e.target.id) );
}
```

```css
#container{
  height:1000px;
}
#div1, #div2{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:2em;
  margin:3em;
}
#div2{
  display:none;
}
#container>div>div{
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding:0.5em;
  margin:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">

  <div id="div1">
    <div> When I am clicked I will open div2 </div>
    <div> I also do the same. </div>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <div> I can be clicked and all the div's stay open </div>
    <div> I also do the same. </div>
    <div> And me too! </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: does the stopPropagation has a herritage, lets say that div2 has multiple elements inside that can be clicked, does one need to repeat the e.stopPropagation(); in each instruction?

Comment: Any element within `div2` (child of `div2`) will be affected by the handler... Unless the child also has a `stopPropagation()`. -- Think about the event being triggered on an element. The browser looks UP to find a handler and applies the last found. You can stop that lookout. That is from the clicked element to its top most parent (`<html>` if nothing stops).

Comment: Basically, you could say (in human language): I'm a container and I don't listen to my parents handlers anymore (on a specific event or set of events). My childs will llisten to my handlers now. ;) It's like you break the chain.

Comment: I updated the snippet with a function to make the clicked element obvious in console.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this the code written with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ( e.currentTarget.id == 'div1' ) {
        $("#div2").show();
    } else if ( e.currentTarget.id == 'div2' ) {
        $("#div1").hide();
    } else {
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

or in plain Javascript:

```
function handleClicks(e) {
    var first = document.getElementById('div1'),
        second = document.getElementById('div2');
    if ( e.currentTarget.id == 'div1' ) {
        second.style.display = 'block';
    } else if ( e.currentTarget.id == 'div2' ) {
        first.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        first.style.display = 'none';
        second.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClicks, false);
```

Also check the if-else statements there.